# Best way to save users subscription with google-in-app billing in my external database?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, in-app-subscription, google-pay

I'm about to implement google in app payment into my android app and here's the thing:

I have 3 subscriptions levels, let's say noob, normal and pro. My app have a login/signup, besides of google login. I've already implement all the purchase in my app, but now i'm wondering which is the best practice to attach that premium subs payed with google billing, with my users, so i can check each user in the app even if they're sharing a device with the same google account but different subscription level.

---

> *For example: I'm in 'normal' subscription payed with account asd@gmail.com with username MINE21 in my nexus 5
>
> Then my sister buys a 'pro' subscription payed with account she@gmail.com with
> username SHE123 in her Galaxy S6, but then she grab my Nexus 5 and
> logins with SHE123 but in playstore i'm logged as asd@gmail.com.
>
> At that moment, i want to show all the pro features to her, but i need
> to confirm if SHE123 is premium even if that the playstore account is
> asd@gmail.com linked with MINE21.*

---

If i'm not being clear explaining myself please let me know.

Am i right if i get the userid from the user buying the subscription, and saving it in my database with the google account id, token purchase and premium level?

I wanna know how can i do to check the google payment with each user of my database even if they're using another google account in play store.

*--My db is a MySQL database handled with PHP--*

Regards,
Inrovero

**I'm going to put my process payment here:**

```
private void processPayment(final String SKU){
    PurchasesUpdatedListener purchasesUpdatedListener = new PurchasesUpdatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPurchasesUpdated(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<Purchase> list) {
            // To be implemented
            if(billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && list != null){
                // do Something you want
                Log.i(TAG, "Compra exitosa");
                // Preparar categoría de premium
                premium = "";
                if(list.get(0).getSku().equals(SKU_BS)) premium = "BS";
                else if(list.get(0).getSku().equals(SKU_BN)) premium = "BN";
                else if(list.get(0).getSku().equals(SKU_BP)) premium = "BP";
                Toast.makeText(mContext, premium + " adquirido", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // Sincronizar premium con la DB y suscripción con el usuario
                User currentUser = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(mContext).getUser();
                int uid = currentUser.getId();
                // Datos a sincronizar
                AccountIdentifiers accountIdentifiers = list.get(0).getAccountIdentifiers();
                String accID = accountIdentifiers.getObfuscatedAccountId();
                String token = list.get(0).getPurchaseToken();
                // Pasar a la DB el token, accID y uid vinculados con el premium.
                // UID // ACCID // TOKEN // PREMIUM //

            }else if(billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED){
                // do Something you want
                Log.i(TAG, "Compra cancelada");
                // Nada? Cancelar all?
            }else if(billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_UNAVAILABLE){
                Log.i(TAG, "Item inexistente");
            }
        }
    };

    final BillingClient billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(mContext)
            .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
            .enablePendingPurchases()
            .build();

    billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBillingSetupFinished(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult) {
            if(billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK){
                // The BillingClient is ready. You can query purchases here.

                List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();
                skuList.add(SKU);
                SkuDetailsParams params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                        .setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS)
                        .build();

                billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params, new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSkuDetailsResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<SkuDetails> list) {
                        if(list == null){
                            Log.i(TAG, "lista vacía");
                            return;
                        }
                        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
                            Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(list.get(i)));
                        }
                        BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                                .setSkuDetails(list.get(0))
                                .build();
                        int responseCode = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(requireActivity(), billingFlowParams).getResponseCode();

                        if(responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK){
                            // do Something you want
                            Log.i(TAG, "responseCode OK");
                        }else if(responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ERROR){
                            Log.i(TAG, "responseCode ERROR");
                        }else if(responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_UNAVAILABLE){
                            Log.i(TAG, "responseCode ITEM_UNAVAILABLE");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
            // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When purchase is sucsses send http request to your php server and put the subscription az int
For example int if noob=1 if pro=2

And save it in your database on your server
Than you can create http request from your php to get that number so you know what subscription user have

You can even set string for more understandable form

So if user x have int = 1 you know that is noob subcription
Than do what you want

I hope it will help you figure out

Comment: Thanks! Yes, i'm going to do that that, but it's a monthly subscription, so i want to make it with google payment data so i can check from my database to google if the user is still paying monthly to know if i need to revoke the premium access to that user in my database.

Comment: @Inroo ok if you want know user pay every month you can use date to time that user buy it save time that user buy it as format y/m/day and create date field of current date than you can compare times to see and lastly for know how many times user buy subscriptions you can create int on your database start from 0 than every time user buy it do + i mean 1.2.3.4 with php than you can see user hiw many time he buy it buy int number if this help plz up vote my answer thanks :) have good day.